# Gitlab CI keeps binaries from previous pipelines

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

We are having a problem with gitlab CI keeping files from previous pipeline.

If the following pipeline in run twice in a short period of time, it seems that nuget packages from previous pipeline are visible to the next pipeline.

For example

1. Pipeline is run for the first time and *Project_1.8.7.nupkg* is created
2. *Project_1.8.7.nupkg* is pushed as expected
3. Pipeline is run second time and *Project_1.8.8.nupkg* is created
4. Nuget tries to push both *1.8.7* and *1.8.8* version which fails, because *1.8.7* already exists

Question is how does the second pipeline know about *1.8.7* ? I would expect that artifact are completely separated (even if they are the same name) and that new docker container is created for each job, so the file is not available for the second run.

This does not happen every time, so i suspect some kind of caching, but cannot discover where.

```
build:
  dependencies: []
  script:
    - dotnet pack ${PATH_TO_SLN} -c Release -o PackagesOutput -p:PackageVersion="${PACKAGE_VERSION}"
  artifacts:
    name: PackedNuget
    paths:
      - PackagesOutput/*

release:
  stage: release
  image: $DOCKER_IMAGE_LINUX
  tags:
    - docker-shared
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  before_script:
    - dotnet nuget add source "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/nuget/index.json" --name gitlab_for_push --username gitlab-ci-token --password ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} --store-password-in-clear-text
  script:
    - dotnet nuget push "PackagesOutput/*.nupkg" --source gitlab_for_push
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'master'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like it is a cache issue

You can list the local caches with this command:

```
nuget locals all -list
```

You can try clearing all caches with this command before you start your tasks:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

Refer to this and see if any of the other cache clear options helps you

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-locals